# How to preload icon font in angular ssr?

Tags: html, angular, preload

I want to preload icons and fonts before html gets rendered. I am using preload strategy to achieve this.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EbDesktopApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/eb-icons/eb-icons.eot" as="font" type="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/eb-icons/eb-icons.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/eb-icons/eb-icons.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/eb-icons/eb-icons.svg" as="font" type="image/svg+xml" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/helvetica-geo/Linotype-HelveticaNeueLTGEO55Roman.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/helvetica-geo/Linotype-HelveticaNeueLTGEO65Medium.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/helvetica-geo/Linotype-HelveticaNeueLTGEO75Bold.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/helvetica-geo/Linotype-HelveticaNeueLTGEO95Black.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
</head>
<body>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is html starts rendering before icons finish load and also I can't see `eb-icons.eot` and `eb-icons.svg` in network tab.

[image]

The question is what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: What do you get in your network tab? Also, depending on the browser it could be possible that those files don't get loaded. At least that's what Google Fonts does.

Comment: Also, this might not work on Firefox, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @MihailMinkov I have edited the question.

Comment: I added an answer and also updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I am no pro on this subject, but I searched a little on this and it might be related to priority or importance of loading.

I would recommend you check [this article](https://andydavies.me/blog/2019/02/12/preloading-fonts-and-the-puzzle-of-priorities/) which deals with font preloading and details on several different options.

Also, you can check more on priorities [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization).

I would recommend you check which file formats you really need, that could reduce your file loading. You could use only Woff ([Woff compatibility](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=woff)) in a combination with TTF ([TTF Compatibility](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=ttf)).